# Error when using GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data

```
mobile(id, name)
mobile(1, 'Nokia')
mobile(2, 'Samsung')
mobile(3, 'Motorola')
```

And categories

```
categories(id, name, mobile_id)
categories(1, 'mobile', '1,2,3')
```

And mysql:

```
SELECT cat.name as cat_name, GROUP_CONCAT(mobile.name) as mobile_name
FROM `mobile` as mobile
LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` AS cat ON cat.mobile_id = mobile.id
```

How to this result:

```
(1,"mobile","Nokia,Samsung,Motorola")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding

```
GROUP cat.name
```

at the end of your query

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `GROUP BY cat.id` 
because `GROUP_CONCAT` is a `GROUP BY (Aggregate) Function`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new table 'mobiles_categories' coupling the mobiles to their respective categories, like so:

`mobile_category`

- id_category - id_mobile
- 1 - 1
- 1 - 2
- 1 - 3
- 2 - 1
- 2 - 2

Doing this you can simply join the categories.